# Flattening multiple heterogenous lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, chain

There are many posts about flattening lists in python, for example here:

[Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

However, I cannot accomplish the flattening I want using the syntax at those sites, to the best of my knowledge.

my list looks like this:

```
TargetArray=(line[0:6], AlleleNumber, AltAlleleCount,HQscoreindex,GeneAnnotationFields)
```

which corresponds to:

```
(['16', '31363977', '.', 'C', 'T', '.'], 2, 1, '1061,925', ['CGA_FI=3687', 'NM_000887.3', 'ITGAX', 'TSS-UPSTREAM', 'UNKNOWN-INC'])
```

So the first and last items are themselves lists I would like to expand. I have tried several approaches, including most recently

```
TargetArray=(line[0:6], AlleleNumber, AltAlleleCount,HQscoreindex,GeneAnnotationFields)
print(TargetArray)
FlatArray=itertools.chain(TargetArray[0])
print(list(FlatArray))
```

But I cannot seem to get the syntax to work out, perhaps because many of the other examples are more uniform in nature.

Comment: suggested reading: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of flattening after the fact, just build the list *directly* by concatenation:

```
TargetArray = line[:6] + [AlleleNumber, AltAlleleCount,HQscoreindex] + GeneAnnotationFields
```